# Can't compile anymore since nuget is down

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Looks like Nuget is currently down. Unfortuantely, I cannot compile my projects anymore too at the moment.
Wha's a good way around this? Deinstall it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't get to NuGet.org either at the moment.

If you are accessing packages that you have already downloaded. You can follow the instructions Scott Hanselman provided here: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToAccessNuGetWhenNuGetorgIsDownOrYoureOnAPlane.aspx